# WebSphere 8.5.5.9 not shipped with SDK 8

Tags: java, java-8, websphere, websphere-8

In our project we are migrating from WebSphere 7 (Java 6) to 8.5.5.9 (Java 8). We chose this precise version because it supports Java 8.

Somehow, we got installed 8.5.5.9 just with SDK 1.6.

[image: jdk 8 installed, but WAS with support up to java 6]

Is there any special fix to be installed with the IBM Installation Manager, besides the default WAS 8.5.5.9 setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to 8.5.5.11, WebSphere Application Server comes with IBM Java SDK 6 as the default embedded Java SDK.  So, what you saw is correct.

Starting in 8.5.5.11, due to impending end of service of Java SE 6, there is the option to have IBM Java SDK 8 as the embedded default.

Moreover, IBM Java SDK 8 is always available as an optional extension that you can install on top of your WAS install.  (The same for Java SDK 7.)

So, you have 2 options.  Since you are migrating and starting from scratch, the 1st route of starting with 8.5.5.11 (or above) and using IBM Java SDK 8 as the default is likely the cleaner and easier.

More information can be found at:

- [Installing Java SDK 8](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_installation_jdk8.html)
- [Java SE 6 End of Service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/covr_javase6_eos.html)

Comment: Thank you, @ykchang. I will ask our sysadmins to get for us the SDK 8 following your link :-)

Comment: Finally our system admins preferred to install v.8.5.5.11, which comes with SDK 8 installed by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - please note that the Java version, that you've printed above, most probably looks like Oracle JVM. WebSphere needs IBM JDK.

We followed these steps to upgrade WAS 8.5.5.9 to IBM Java SDK 8:

- Download IBM Java SDK 8 from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24043875#SDK80.
- Extract SDK 8 archive.
- Open IBM Installation Manager (you would have used this to install WAS 8.5.5.x).
- Add SDK 8 archive directory as Repository in IM.
- In IM select "Install" and install "IBM WebSphere SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8.x.x".
- Stop the server before running the managesdk command.
- Run command and note SDK 8 name (e.g. 1.8_64):

  .\managesdk.bat -listAvailable
- Update profile to use SDK 8:
  e.g.

  .\managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv01 -sdkname 1.8_64 -enableServers
- Verify profile update:

  .\managesdk.bat -listEnabledProfileAll

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer. Anyhow, this solution would not have helped us as we don't have access to these servers except through admin console (with exception of local installed server). As stated above, we finally got v8.5.5.11 which finally shipped SDK 8 by default.